# Remover IIS Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis, iis-7

Boa tarde, possuo `Windows Server 2008 R2 x64`, estou precisando desinstalar por completo o servidor web (`IIS`), pois pretendo utilizar o servidor `Apache` no seu lugar.
No painel gerenciador de servidores cliquei no botão direito em cima de Servidor Web (`IIS`) e escolhi a opção Remover Serviços de Função.
Conforme imagem em anexa, não consigo clicar em próximo para continuar a remoção. Acredito que preciso desinstalar algo antes. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado.

[image: Print da janela para remover o Servidor Web (<code>IIS</code>)]

[image: Print da janela dos serviços parados]

Comment: Experimenta parar o serviço do iis em "services.msc" antes de desinstalar. Precisa de role de Administrador.

Comment: Parei os seguintes serviços: Serviço Auxiliar de Host do Aplicativo (APPHOSTSVC) ,Serviço de Administração do IIS (IISADMIN), Serviço de Ativação de Processos do Windows (WAS), Serviço do Estado ASP.NEt (aspnet_state) , Serviço de Publicação da World Wide Web (W3SVC). O problema ainda persiste.

Comment: Se o serviço estiver desativado e/ou se não tiver ninguém mais usando a porta, você pode instalar o apache e usar a porta 80. Já deve funcionar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no penúltimo comando deste [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205471(v=wps.630).aspx).

Comment: Verifica se o `WAS`(Windows Process Activation Service) está instalado antes de proceder, se o mesmo estiver você não vai conseguir desinstalar o `IIS` porque ele é dependente.